# ～なあに at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, definitions

I borrowed a Japanese children's book from the library to practice and of course I'm stuck on the title. It is called ごあいさつなあに。I know the first part means greetings or welcome, but I can't find any information online about the ending part tacked on. I figure its a colloquial type of thing.

Comment: 一応辞書に・・・　http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/なあに

Answer (score 1):

It's just a singsongy way of saying the word 何{なに} ("what").

There seems to be a whole series of these picture books with titles ending in なあに, which would all translate into English as something like "What's [X]". So there's おてんきなあに "What's the Weather?", このかたちなあに "What's This Shape?" and so forth. This one, ごあいさつなあに, would be something along the lines of "What are Greetings?"